# sort an object array based on property of another object array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

i have two object arrays in js.dummy arrays are shown below.

```
arr1=[{'id':1,'name':'David'},
      {'id':2,'name':'Miles'},
      {'id':3,'name':'John'},];

arr2=[{'id':2,'age':22},
      {'id':3,'age':18},
      {'id':1,'age':12},];
```

Can i sort arr1 in same order of ids as arr2. so arr1 becomes

```
[{'id':2,'name':'Miles'},
      {'id':3,'name':'John'},
      {'id':1,'name':'David'},];
```

actual arrays have some 900 objects each.so is there any efficient method of achieving this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reduce` the second array to a `Map` indexed by `id`s, then use `Map.get` to identify the location of the id while sorting. `Map`s have guaranteed O(1) lookup time:

```js
const arr1 = [{'id':1,'name':'David'},{'id':2,'name':'Miles'},{'id':3,'name':'John'},];
const arr2 = [{'id':2,'age':22},{'id':3,'age':18},{'id':1,'age':12},];

const ids = arr2.reduce((map, { id }, i) => map.set(id, i), new Map());
arr1.sort((a, b) => ids.get(a.id) - ids.get(b.id));
console.log(arr1);
```

Still, 900 objects is not much at all in the modern day.

Answer (score 1):

```
// cache arr1 id to index, id is key, index is value
let arr1IdToIndex = arr1.reduce((sum, cur, index) => (sum[cur.id] = index, sum), {})
let result = arr2.map(cur => arr1[arr1IdToIndex[cur.id]])
arr1 = result
```